# importing jquery plugin is not work in react app

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-plugins

I try to import a jquery flexslider plugin in Slider component. But it's give me error " $(this.el).flexSlider() is not a function  ". And in My text editor it's also show me i declier flexSlider variable but never use.

I load jquery in my index.html file and also in my Slider component. And in my Slider component in import flexslider which I installed by npm.

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import flexSlider from 'flexslider';

class Slider extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.flexSlider();
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="slider" ref={el=> this.el = el}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default Slider;
```

That give me the error " $(this.el).flexSlider() is not a function "

Comment: i thik you need to check how to correclty import the flex slider

Comment: In documentation they only give the example of using script tag. Their is no information about es6 import statement

Comment: i also try other plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Create one component jQuery, example (components/Jquery.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import jQuery from 'jquery' // Import directly from node-modules
window.jQuery = jQuery

export default () => (jQuery)
```

In your component you will use a jQuery plugin, example (components/Slider.js):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import $ from './Jquery' // Import component
import flexSlider from 'flexslider' // Import directly from node-modules

class Slider extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
         $(".hero-slider").flexslider({
            controlNav: true,
            directionNav: false,
            animation: "fade"
        });
    }

    render = () => (
        <div className="hero hero-slider">
        <ul className="slides">
            <li data-bg-image="dummy/slider-1.jpg">
            <div className="container">
                         <h3 className="slider-subtitle">Your header goes here</h3>
            <h2 className="slider-title">Professional</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa molestiae necessitatibus possimus ducimus facere, error, nostrum. Quos sapiente ducimus maxime odio alias dolor consequuntur, maiores commodi exercitationem veniam. Id, ex?</p>
            <a href="#" className="button large">Read more</a>
            </div>
        </li>
                 <li data-bg-image="dummy/slider-2.jpg">
            <div className="container">
                <h3 className="slider-subtitle">Your header goes here</h3>
            <h2 className="slider-title">Professional</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In maiores illo eligendi obcaecati reiciendis, vel perspiciatis aliquid esse architecto deleniti asperiores, laboriosam nemo rerum! Ipsam numquam delectus minus iure sit!</p>
            <a href="#" className="button large">Read more</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li data-bg-image="dummy/slider-3.jpg">
            <div className="container">
            <h3 className="slider-subtitle">Your header goes here</h3>
            <h2 className="slider-title">Professional</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam iure, alias error suscipit porro quidem minus, autem repellendus rerum labore corrupti! Quia quas, architecto, quis non pariatur quisquam nisi magnam.</p>
            <a href="#" className="button large">Read more</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Slider
```

Just an example. Understand this to implement in your code.